# magento 2 error - "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: product, rest-api, magento2.2.2, best-seller

I have a custom module to expose an API to get the best selling products & most viewed products separately.

This module is working fine in my localhost and staging server. When i moved the same code to production server i am getting an error like below.

> "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Ayakil\Insights\Api\ProductSlidersManagementInterface in /chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111\nStack trace:\n#0 /chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Ayakil\\Insig...', Array)\n#1 /chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Ayakil\\Insig...')\n#2 /chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(328): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Ayakil\\Insig...')\n#3 /chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()\n#4 /chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magent' in '/chroot/home/aee9c6e2/aaa2d0443a.nxcli.net/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php' on line 111"

My custom modules **di.xml** file is below.

My **ProductSlidersManagement.php** file is below.

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\Insights\Api;
interface ProductSlidersManagementInterface
{
 /**
 * Get Bestseller Product Slider api
 * @return \Ayakil\Insights\Api\Data\ProductSlidersInterface
 */    
public function getBestseller();
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Show di.xml file, there may be errors. Also, if they are not, use:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

My custom modules di.xml file is below. is not visible or you skip (forget) to add here and yes, do not use the ObjectManager instead use _constructor. I have myself experienced that in production mode in a few places Object managers do not work.